# ScrollView inside a UIStackView

Tags: uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

Here is my view hierarchy

-- UIStackView --- UIScrollView -- UIImageView

StackView distribution is set to `.FillProportionally` but this not working since the UIScrollView doesn't have intrinsic content size.

So my question is since the UIIMageView has intrinsic content size, is there any way for me to pass that content size to UIScrollView so the StackView can show the proper size for the view.

I already tried setting the `contentSize` of scrollView based on `width` and `height` of the `UIImageView` but doesn't seem to be working either.

I am also not sure where to set the constraint if that that is an alternative approach, I need to have a dynamic size for the ScrollView based on the `contentSize` of ImageView so a fixed constraint won't help either.

I should also point out the reason for having the `ImageView` as subview of `scrollView` is to be able to resize `ImageView` inside `StackView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question

You need to override `intrinsicContentSize` property of `UIScrollView`

In this case

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    if let image = imageView.image {
        return CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height)
    }
    return CGSizeMake(0, 0)
}
```